# I need to make a nested accordion with VANILLA JS, not jquery, i have a problem opening inner accordions

Tags: javascript

So, I made a nested accordion, and it works find with outer elements, but inner elements don't seem to be expanding, when I click them, the outer gets `display:none`. If someone could explain their answer if they have one, I have been doing this for 2 days, and I'm getting tired of it very much. I have put the accordion inside of an outer accordion to have same class, and I loop them from the JS file, but it just seems pointless at this point I think, I lost 2 days on this task :(

```js
const accordionItem = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion--item");
const accordionContent = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion__content");
const accordionNested = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion--nested");
for (let i = 0; i < accordionItem.length; i++) {
  accordionItem[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    accordionItem[i].classList.add("accordion--open");
    accordionContent[i].style.display = "block";
    e.stopPropagation();
    for (let j = 0; j < accordionItem.length; j++) {
      if (j != i) {
        accordionContent[j].style.display = "none";
        accordionItem[j].classList.remove("accordion--open");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/**
 * Required CSS 
 */
.accordion__title {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.accordion__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 24px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.accordion__icon .line-01,
.accordion__icon .line-02 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #272343;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.accordion__icon .line-02 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.accordion__content {
  display: none;
}

.accordion--open > .accordion__title .line-02 {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
/* end Required CSS */

/**
 * Now let's make it look pretty! 
 */
body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 5%;
  color: #111;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

.accordion {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #272343;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #272343;
}

.accordion__title {
  padding: 20px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.accordion__content {
  padding: 24px 16px;
}

.accordion__content p {
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}

.accordion__title:hover {
  background-color: #433d6f;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion__title:hover .line-01,
.accordion__title:hover .line-02 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.accordion--open > .accordion__title {
  background-color: #272343;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion--open > .accordion__title .line-01,
.accordion--open > .accordion__title .line-02 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.accordion--nested .accordion__title {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.accordion--nested .accordion__content {
  padding: 24px 16px 16px;
}
.slideUp {
  height: 0;
}
.slideDown {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/nested.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>JS accordion</h1>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion--item">
            <h4 class="accordion__title">
                Accordion Title 01
                <i class="accordion__icon">
                    <div class="line-01"></div>
                    <div class="line-02"></div>
                </i>
            </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Accordion Nested Title 01
                        <i class="accordion__icon">
                            <div class="line-01"></div>
                            <div class="line-02"></div>
                        </i>
                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio.</p>
                        <p>Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra
                            non, semper
                            suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 01 -->
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Accordion Nested Title 02
                        <i class="accordion__icon">
                            <div class="line-01"></div>
                            <div class="line-02"></div>
                        </i>
                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio.</p>
                        <p>Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra
                            non, semper
                            suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 02 -->
            </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
        </div><!-- end .accordion 01 -->

        <div class="accordion--item">
            <h4 class="accordion__title">
                Accordion Title 02
                <i class="accordion__icon">
                    <div class="line-01"></div>
                    <div class="line-02"></div>
                </i>
            </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Accordion Nested Title 01
                        <i class="accordion__icon">
                            <div class="line-01"></div>
                            <div class="line-02"></div>
                        </i>
                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio.</p>
                        <p>Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra
                            non, semper
                            suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 01 -->
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Accordion Nested Title 02
                        <i class="accordion__icon">
                            <div class="line-01"></div>
                            <div class="line-02"></div>
                        </i>
                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio.</p>
                        <p>Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra
                            non, semper
                            suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 02 -->
            </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
        </div><!-- end .accordion 02 -->

        <div class="accordion--item">
            <h4 class="accordion__title">
                Accordion Title 03
                <i class="accordion__icon">
                    <div class="line-01"></div>
                    <div class="line-02"></div>
                </i>
            </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Accordion Nested Title 01
                        <i class="accordion__icon">
                            <div class="line-01"></div>
                            <div class="line-02"></div>
                        </i>
                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio.</p>
                        <p>Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra
                            non, semper
                            suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 01 -->
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Accordion Nested Title 02
                        <i class="accordion__icon">
                            <div class="line-01"></div>
                            <div class="line-02"></div>
                        </i>
                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio.</p>
                        <p>Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra
                            non, semper
                            suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 02 -->
            </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
        </div><!-- end .accordion 03 -->
    </div>
</body>
<script src="./nested.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put code to open parent accordion itens.
See the code between `// BEGIN: Open parent accordion` and `// END: Open parent accordion`

```js
const accordionItem = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion--item");
const accordionContent = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion__content");
const accordionNested = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion--nested");
for (let i = 0; i < accordionItem.length; i++) {
  accordionItem[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    accordionItem[i].classList.add("accordion--open");
    accordionContent[i].style.display = "block";
    e.stopPropagation();
    for (let j = 0; j < accordionItem.length; j++) {
      if (j != i) {
        accordionContent[j].style.display = "none";
        accordionItem[j].classList.remove("accordion--open");
      }
    }
    // BEGIN: Open parent accordion
    let recursiveNode = accordionItem[i];
    while( (recursiveNode = recursiveNode.parentNode) ){
        if (recursiveNode.classList && recursiveNode.classList.contains('accordion--item')) {
            recursiveNode.classList.add("accordion--open");
            let recursiveNodeChildren = recursiveNode.childNodes;
            for(let j = 0; j < recursiveNodeChildren.length; j++) {
               let childNode = recursiveNodeChildren[j];
               if (childNode.classList && childNode.classList.contains('accordion__content')) {
                   childNode.style.display = "block";
                   break;
               }
            }
            
        }
    }
    // END: Open parent accordion
  });
}
```

```css
/**
 * Required CSS 
 */
.accordion__title {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.accordion__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 24px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.accordion__icon .line-01,
.accordion__icon .line-02 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #272343;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.accordion__icon .line-02 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.accordion__content {
  display: none;
}

.accordion--open > .accordion__title .line-02 {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
/* end Required CSS */

/**
 * Now let's make it look pretty! 
 */
body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 5%;
  color: #111;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

.accordion {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #272343;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #272343;
}

.accordion__title {
  padding: 20px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.accordion__content {
  padding: 24px 16px;
}

.accordion__content p {
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}

.accordion__title:hover {
  background-color: #433d6f;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion__title:hover .line-01,
.accordion__title:hover .line-02 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.accordion--open > .accordion__title {
  background-color: #272343;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion--open > .accordion__title .line-01,
.accordion--open > .accordion__title .line-02 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.accordion--nested .accordion__title {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.accordion--nested .accordion__content {
  padding: 24px 16px 16px;
}
.slideUp {
  height: 0;
}
.slideDown {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/nested.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>JS accordion</h1>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion--item">
            <h4 class="accordion__title">
                Accordion Title 01
                <i class="accordion__icon">
                    <div class="line-01"></div>
                    <div class="line-02"></div>
                </i>
            </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Accordion Nested Title 01
                        <i class="accordion__icon">
                            <div class="line-01"></div>
                            <div class="line-02"></div>
                        </i>
                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio.</p>
                        <p>Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra
                            non, semper
                            suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 01 -->
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Accordion Nested Title 02
                        <i class="accordion__icon">
                            <div class="line-01"></div>
                            <div class="line-02"></div>
                        </i>
                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio.</p>
                        <p>Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra
                            non, semper
                            suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 02 -->
            </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
        </div><!-- end .accordion 01 -->

        <div class="accordion--item">
            <h4 class="accordion__title">
                Accordion Title 02
                <i class="accordion__icon">
                    <div class="line-01"></div>
                    <div class="line-02"></div>
                </i>
            </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Accordion Nested Title 01
                        <i class="accordion__icon">
                            <div class="line-01"></div>
                            <div class="line-02"></div>
                        </i>
                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio.</p>
                        <p>Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra
                            non, semper
                            suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 01 -->
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Accordion Nested Title 02
                        <i class="accordion__icon">
                            <div class="line-01"></div>
                            <div class="line-02"></div>
                        </i>
                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio.</p>
                        <p>Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra
                            non, semper
                            suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 02 -->
            </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
        </div><!-- end .accordion 02 -->

        <div class="accordion--item">
            <h4 class="accordion__title">
                Accordion Title 03
                <i class="accordion__icon">
                    <div class="line-01"></div>
                    <div class="line-02"></div>
                </i>
            </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Accordion Nested Title 01
                        <i class="accordion__icon">
                            <div class="line-01"></div>
                            <div class="line-02"></div>
                        </i>
                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio.</p>
                        <p>Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra
                            non, semper
                            suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 01 -->
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Accordion Nested Title 02
                        <i class="accordion__icon">
                            <div class="line-01"></div>
                            <div class="line-02"></div>
                        </i>
                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio.</p>
                        <p>Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra
                            non, semper
                            suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 02 -->
            </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
        </div><!-- end .accordion 03 -->
    </div>
</body>
<script src="./nested.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Manuel, i figured it out on Friday, but i really appriciate your help, all i did was put a while loop and target one more parent element :D